# N-Queens Solutions C++

Tags: c++, n-queens

So I need help with the classic N-Queens problem.

The command to run the program will be:
***nqueens N k*** - where N is the size of the table (N x N) and k is the number of solutions

So for example if I were to run the program by typing ***nqueens 4 1*** the following would be printed out.

_ Q _ _

_ _ _ Q

Q _ _ _

_ _ Q _

However, I cannot figure out how to handle more than 1 solution? How can I determine more than just one solution for this problem?

What I have so far is below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class Board
{
private:
    bool** spaces;
    int size;

public:
    Board(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        spaces = new bool*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            spaces[i] = new bool[size];
        }
    }

    bool isSafe(int row, int column, vector<int>& state)
    {
       //check row conflict
       //no need to check for column conflicts
       //because the board is beimg filled column
       //by column
       for(int i = 0; i < column; ++i)
       {
          if(state[i] == row)
             return false;
       }

       //check for diagonal conflicts
       int columnDiff = 0;
       int rowDiff = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < column; ++i)
       {
          columnDiff = abs(column - i);
          rowDiff = abs(row - state[i]);
          if(columnDiff == rowDiff)
             return false;
       }

       return true;

    }

    int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    bool getSpace(int x, int y)
    {
        return spaces[y][x];
    }

    void setSpace(int x, int y, bool value)
    {
        spaces[y][x] = value;
    }

    Board(Board& other)
    {
        this->size = other.getSize();
        spaces = new bool*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            spaces[i] = new bool[size];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            {
                spaces[i][j] = other.getSpace(j, i);
            }
        }
    }

    void backtrack(vector<int>& state, int board_size)
  {
     int row = 0;
     int column = 0;
     bool backtrack = false;

     while(column < board_size)
     {
        while(row < board_size)
        {
           if(backtrack)
           {
              row = state[column] + 1;
              if(row == board_size)
              {
                 column--; //backtrack more
                 backtrack = true;
                 row = 0;
                 break;
              }

              backtrack = false;
           }

           if(isSafe(row, column, state))
           {
              state[column] = row;
              row = 0;
              column++; //advance
              backtrack = false;
              break;
           }

           else
           {
              if(row == (board_size - 1))
              {
                 column--; //backtrack
                 backtrack = true;
                 row = 0;
              }
              else
              {
                 row++;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
};

int print_solutions(Board *board, vector<int>& state, int board_size)
{
   for(int i=0; i < board_size; ++i)
   {
      for(int j=0; j < board_size; ++j)
      {
         if(state[i] == j)
            cout << 'Q' << " ";
         else
            cout << '_' << " ";
      }

      cout << endl;
   }
}   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: nqueens [Board Size] [Number of Solutions]" << endl;
    return 1;
    }

    int board_size = atoi(argv[1]);
    //int solution_count = atoi(argv[2]);
    vector<int> state;
    state.resize(board_size);

    Board *my_board = new Board(board_size);
    my_board->backtrack(state, board_size);

    print_solutions(my_board, state, board_size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.igorsevo.com/Article.aspx?article=Recursion+tutorial%2c+N-queens+problem

Comment: Well, `argc < 2` should probably be `argc < 3` since you expect two parameters, then you would likely want to actually use the number of solutions parameter in some way.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution I kept pretty much of the original approach and the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Board
{
private:
    bool** spaces;
    int size;

public:
    Board(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        spaces = new bool*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            spaces[i] = new bool[size];
        }
    }

    bool isSafe(int row, int column, vector<int>& state)
    {
       //check row conflict
       //no need to check for column conflicts
       //because the board is beimg filled column
       //by column
       for(int i = 0; i < column; ++i)
       {
          if(state[i] == row)
             return false;
       }

       //check for diagonal conflicts
       int columnDiff = 0;
       int rowDiff = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < column; ++i)
       {
          columnDiff = abs(column - i);
          rowDiff = abs(row - state[i]);
          if(columnDiff == rowDiff)
             return false;
       }

       return true;

    }

    int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    bool getSpace(int x, int y)
    {
        return spaces[y][x];
    }

    void setSpace(int x, int y, bool value)
    {
        spaces[y][x] = value;
    }

    Board(Board& other)
    {
        this->size = other.getSize();
        spaces = new bool*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            spaces[i] = new bool[size];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            {
                spaces[i][j] = other.getSpace(j, i);
            }
        }
    }

    bool backtrack(vector<int>& state, int& column, int board_size)
  {
     int row = 0;
     bool backtrack = column == board_size;

     while(column < board_size || backtrack)
     {
        {
           if(backtrack)
           {
              if (column == 0)
                 return false;
              column--;
              row = state[column] + 1;
              if(row == board_size)
              {
                 backtrack = true;
                 continue;
              }

              backtrack = false;
           }

           if(isSafe(row, column, state))
           {
              state[column] = row;
              row = 0;
              column++; //advance
              backtrack = false;
              continue;
           }

           else
           {
              if(row == (board_size - 1))
              {
                 backtrack = true;
              }
              else
              {
                 row++;
              }
           }
        }
     }
     return true;
  }
};

void print_solutions(Board *board, vector<int>& state, int board_size)
{
   for(int i=0; i < board_size; ++i)
   {
      for(int j=0; j < board_size; ++j)
      {
         if(state[i] == j)
            cout << 'Q' << " ";
         else
            cout << '_' << " ";
      }

      cout << endl;
   }
    cout << endl;
}   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        cout << "Usage: nqueens [Board Size] [Number of Solutions]" << endl;
    return 1;
    }

    int board_size = atoi(argv[1]);
    int solution_count = atoi(argv[2]);
    vector<int> state;
    state.resize(board_size);

    Board *my_board = new Board(board_size);
    int column = 0;
    while (solution_count-- > 0 && my_board->backtrack(state, column, board_size))
        print_solutions(my_board, state, board_size);

    return 0;
}
```

- fixed: compile error: cout is unknown -> `#include` iostream
- added: extra newline in `print_solutions` to separate multiple solutions
- fixed: `print_solutions` printed the transposed table
- fixed: compile error: `print_solutions` does not return a value -> `void`
- fixed: `argc` check
- added: `solution_count` support by moving `column` to call site
- fixed: backtrack code duplication (`column--`, `row = 0`)
- fixed: unnecessary inner loop (`row < board_size`)
- not fixed: `my_board` is leaked
- not fixed: the whole `Board` class and its instance is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

Here is my brute force recursive solution. It is not optimal one (without backtracking), but works reasonable good for chess boards up to 14 x 14. 
In the recursive method `queensSolution` the first argument is the size of chess board. The second argument encodes actual position of the queens.

For example, vector describing the position on the picture would be {1, 3, 0, 2}. This means: in the first row (count starts with 0, so it is first element of the vector) a queen is on position 1 (second quadrat from left), in the second row (second element in the vector) a queen is placed on position 3 (the last quadrat of the row) etc.

[image]

The third argument contains vector that will contain all solution positions (encoded as vector as described above).
The help method `intersect` checks whether there is a collision between a new queen that will be placed on position {queens.size(), x}. Collisions occur when the new queen is on the same 'column' (x position) as any of existing queens or whether the distances between x positions and y positions of the new queen with any of existing queens are equal (diagonal position). We do not have to check whether the new queen will be placed in a row (y) where some other queen is already placed, because every time we add an element to the `queens` vector we put it in new row.

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

bool intersect(const vector<int> &queens, int x) {
    int y = queens.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        if ((abs(queens[i] - x) == 0) || (abs(queens[i] - x) == y - i))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void queensSolution(const int dim, vector<int> queens, vector<vector<int>> &res) {
    if (queens.size() >= dim) {
        res.push_back(queens);
        queens.clear();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if (!intersect(queens, i)) {
            queens.push_back(i);
            queensSolution(dim, queens, res);
            queens.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

For example, to find all solutions for 4 x 4 chessboard, do following:

```
int main(){
  int dim = 4;
  vector<int>queens;
  vector<vector<int>> result;
  queensSolution(dim, queens, result);
}
```

After `queensSolution` returns, vector result contains two vectors: `{1, 3, 0, 2}` and `{2, 0, 3, 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive approach for solving it. I have written an article about this: [Recursion tutorial: N-queens in C](http://www.igorsevo.com/Article.aspx?article=Recursion%20tutorial,%20N-queens%20problem). To obtain all the solutions, simply run the recursion without terminating for the first solution found.

There is also a heuristic solution available here: [Eight queen puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/iyedb/9300013). It's a simple recursive function that returns all the solutions.
It works by placing each time a queen a the next row. The method `is_safe`checks if it is safe to place a queen at column col in the next row. The solution are vector where the index i is the row and the value at that index is the column. Each time a queen is placed successfully, the vector grows by one element and is added to the set of candidate solutions which are returned back up in the recursive calls stack.